# I was trying to calculate Simple interest amount in VBA by using functions, but it's not working

Tags: vba, function

```
Function InterestAmount(pdblPrincipal As Double, pdblTime As Double, pdblRate As Double, pdblInterestAmount As Double)

    If IsMissing(pdblRate) Then
    MsgBox "Your loan amount is: " & pdblPrincipal
    Else
    pdblInterestAmount = ((pdblPrincipal * pdblTime * pdblRate) / 100)
    End If
    
    ldblInterestAmount = pdblInterestAmount

End Function

Function CalculateInterestAmount(Principal As Double, Time As Double, Rate As Double)

Dim ldblPrincipal As Double
Dim ldblTime As Double
Dim ldblRate As Double
Dim ldblInterestAmount As Double

    ldblInterestAmount = 0
    ldblPrincipal = Principal
    ldblTime = Time
    ldblRate = Rate
    Call InterestAmount(ldblPrincipal, ldblTime, ldblRate, ldblInterestAmount)
    Debug.Print ldblInterestAmount
    
End Function
```

Comment: return ```ldblInterestAmount```

Comment: please [edit] the post and include a description of what `it's not working` means.

Answer (score 0):

Function InterestAmount(pdblPrincipal As Double, pdblTime As Double, pdblRate As Double, pdblInterestAmount As Double)

```
If IsMissing(pdblRate) Then
MsgBox "Your loan amount is: " & pdblPrincipal
Else
pdblInterestAmount = ((pdblPrincipal * pdblTime * pdblRate) / 100)
End If

ldblInterestAmount = pdblInterestAmount
```

End Function

Function CalculateInterestAmount(Principal As Double, Time As Double, Rate As Double)

Dim ldblPrincipal As Double
Dim ldblTime As Double
Dim ldblRate As Double
Dim ldblInterestAmount As Double

```
ldblInterestAmount = 0
ldblPrincipal = Principal
ldblTime = Time
ldblRate = Rate
Call InterestAmount(ldblPrincipal, ldblTime, ldblRate, ldblInterestAmount)
Debug.Print ldblInterestAmount
```

End Function